# How can I sort a GraphQL query based on the frontmatter

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am new to `GraphQL` and have successfully sorted data with an `allMarkDownRemark` query, however what I need is to be able to us a `allFile` query and then still sort by the `frontmatter`, is this possible?

This is the query which (with the sort removed) returns the correct data.

```
{
    allFile(
      limit: 3
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___priority], order: DESC }
      filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "key-points" } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          childMarkdownRemark {
            frontmatter {
              title
              content
              priority
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run it with the sort in like I above it throws the following error

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected type FileConnectionSortByFieldsEnum, found frontmatter___priority.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 28
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Firstly is there a way to query using `AllFile` and then sort via the `frontmatter`?

If not then is there a way to filter a specific folder with markdown info without a `path` field?

Comment: Is this a public GraphQL api you are querying? Can you share the schema of the API? Without that no one guess if the ´sort´ parameter is available.

Comment: shan, you didn't add information that you use Gatsby

Comment: Yeah should have said this is with Gatsby, I have changed the query now to use allMarkdownRemark instead and this has worked fine

Answer (score 3):

> Firstly is there a way to query using AllFile and then sort via the frontmatter?

Without changes in [gatsby-source-filesystem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-filesystem) it's not possible. You should use one of `FileConnectionSortByFieldsEnum` values. There is `FileConnectionSortByFieldsEnum` values:

- id
- children
- parent
- internal___contentDigest
- internal___type
- internal___mediaType
- internal___description
- internal___owner
- sourceInstanceName
- absolutePath
- relativePath
- extension
- size
- prettySize
- modifiedTime
- accessTime
- changeTime
- birthTime
- root
- dir
- base
- ext
- name
- relativeDirectory
- dev
- mode
- nlink
- uid
- gid
- rdev
- blksize
- ino
- blocks
- atimeMs
- mtimeMs
- ctimeMs
- birthtimeMs
- atime
- mtime
- ctime
- birthtime
- publicURL

> If not then is there a way to filter a specific folder with markdown info without a path field?

Change query to use allMarkdownRemark, it should help you.