# Gatsby GraphQL query only sorts by first index of value?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

What I'm trying to do is sort a number of folders based on the folder's title. ie: `1_folderTitle, 2_folderTitle, 3_folderTitle`

My file structure looks like this:

```
 content   
    │
    └───portfolio
        │
        └───1_project1
        │   │   image.png
        │   │   index.md
        │
        └───2_project2
            │   image.png
            │   index.md
```

Currently, my query is working up until I have 10 folders. Once there are more than 10 folders, the 10 is sorted as 1.

**Here's my query:**

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
     allFile(
        filter: {
          sourceInstanceName: { eq: "content" }
          extension: { eq: "md" }
          relativeDirectory: { regex: "/portfolio/" }
        }
        sort: { fields: [dir], order: DESC }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                stack
                description
                type
                image {
                  childImageSharp{
                    fluid(maxWidth:800, quality:80){
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              html
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

I've attempted to sort by frontmatter, but I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825195/how-can-i-sort-a-graphql-query-based-on-the-frontmatter) stating that it's not possible when querying using allFile.

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: Rename the folders?

Comment: @ksav the point is to sort based on the numbers at the beginning of the folder name. It will only sort 0-9, 10 is sorted as 1.